# I want to stop text to speech method when user returning from another activity to MainActivity

Tags: java, android

Basically i have two java activities where i have implemented textToSpeech in one activity but when i go to another activity using on click view and when i pressed back for returning to the mainactivity then it will again execute texttospeech method.
But **i want to execute this method only once when the user starts the app after that it will stop.**
Below is my code and i want to execute the code only once how it will done?

```
package com.example.software2.ocrhy;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
    private static int firstTime = 0;
    private TextView mVoiceInputTv;
    float x1, x2, y1, y2;
    private TextView mSpeakBtn;

    private static TextToSpeech textToSpeech;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(1.1f);
                    if (firstTime == 0)
                        textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(1.1f);
                    textToSpeech.speak("Welcome to Blind App. Swipe left to listen the features of the app or swipe right and say what you want", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }
        });
        mVoiceInputTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.voiceInput);

   }
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchEvent) {
        firstTime = 1;
        switch (touchEvent.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x1 = touchEvent.getX();
                y1 = touchEvent.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x2 = touchEvent.getX();
                y2 = touchEvent.getY();
                if (x1 < x2) {
                    textToSpeech.speak(" Say Read for reading,  calculator for calculator,  time and date,  weather for weather,  battery for battery. Swipe right and say what you want ", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                } else if (x1 > x2) {
                    startVoiceInput();
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void startVoiceInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hello, How can I help you?");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                mVoiceInputTv.setText(result.get(0));

                if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("read")) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
                } else {
                    textToSpeech.speak("Do not understand just tap on the screen Say again", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                }
                if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("calculator")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity3.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
                } else {
                    textToSpeech.speak("Do not understand just tap on the screen Say again", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
                if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("time and date")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity4.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
                } else {
                    textToSpeech.speak("Do not understand just tap on the screen Say again", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
                if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("weather")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity5.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
                } else {
                    textToSpeech.speak("Do not understand just tap on the screen Say again", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }

                if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("battery")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity6.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
                } else {
                    textToSpeech.speak("Do not understand tap on the screen Say again", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
                if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("yes")) {
                    textToSpeech.speak("  Say Read for reading,  calculator for calculator,  time and date,  weather for weather,  battery for battery. Do you want to listen again", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
                } else if ((mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("no"))) {
                    textToSpeech.speak("then tap on the screen and say what you want", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                }
            } else if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("exit")) {
                finish();

            }
        }
    }




    public void onPause() {
        if (textToSpeech != null) {
            textToSpeech.stop();
        }
        super.onPause();

    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @Nullable KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
            textToSpeech.speak("You are already in the main menu", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }


        return true;
    }


    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: attach more code in question

Comment: I have added my full code of mainactivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace these code in your **MainActivity.class**

```
private static final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
private static  int firstTime = 0;
private TextView mVoiceInputTv;
private ImageButton mSpeakBtn;

private static TextToSpeech textToSpeech;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                if (firstTime == 0)
                    textToSpeech.speak("Welcome to Blind App. Tap on the screen. Say Read for reading . Say  calculator  for calculator.say time and date. say weather for weather. say battery for battery.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        }
    });
    mVoiceInputTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.voiceInput);
    mSpeakBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    mSpeakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            firstTime = 1;
            startVoiceInput();
        }
    });
}

private void startVoiceInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hello, How can I help you?");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        a.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            mVoiceInputTv.setText(result.get(0));

        }

        if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("read")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
        }
        if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("calculator")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity3.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
        }
        if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("time and date")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity4.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
        }
        if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("weather")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity5.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
        }
        if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("battery")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity6.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
        }
    }
}

public void onPause() {
    if (textToSpeech != null) {
        textToSpeech.stop();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Brother can you help me how can i add firsttime = 1 in onTouchEvent in my java code which is given above.

Comment: share your source code

Comment: I have updated the source code in question.

Comment: Hey you got the answer

Comment: create if condition body in onInit method

Comment: and also another status ike 0,1,2 etc...

Comment: Can you give the answer of this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70862919?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1):

Make Text to Speak variable in Global and at these code in your **onStop / onPause method**.

```
public static void releaseTts() {
 if (mTts != null) {
   mTts.stop();
   mTts.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying