# I am working on OCR reader application. below is my java code. My question is how to start another method if one is completed?

Tags: java, android

1. When the user captures the image, the device will automatically read aloud the text. for that i have implemented texttospeech method but when this activity stop i want to start another task. how will it can be done?
2. ***After reading the captured text, I want to implement another text-to-speech method how can i do this?***

```
package com.example.software2.ocrhy;

import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_SPEECH = 101;
    private static final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
    Button buttonCamera;
    private Button button;
    private TextView mVoiceInputTv;
    private TextView textView;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private CameraSource cameraSource;
    private TextRecognizer textRecognizer;
    private static TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private String stringResult = null;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        mVoiceInputTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{CAMERA}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.CANADA);
                    textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(1f);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "tap on the screen and say yes for read and no for return to the main menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    textToSpeech.speak("tap on the screen and say yes for read and no for return to the main menu", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void textRecognizer() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Tap on the screen and listen ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        textToSpeech.speak(" Tap on the screen take a picture of any text with your device and listen", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();
        surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

        Context context = this;
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });
    }

    private void capture() {
        textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
                SparseArray<TextBlock> sparseArray = detections.getDetectedItems();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < sparseArray.size(); ++i) {
                    TextBlock textBlock = sparseArray.valueAt(i);
                    if (textBlock != null && textBlock.getValue() != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(textBlock.getValue() + " ");
                    }
                }

                final String stringText = stringBuilder.toString();

                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        stringResult = stringText;
                        resultObtained();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void resultObtained() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(stringResult);
        textToSpeech.speak(stringResult, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
        

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startVoiceInput();
        }
    });
}


    private void startVoiceInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hello, How can I help you?");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().contentEquals("time and date")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity4.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().contentEquals("battery")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity6.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
                }
                if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().contentEquals("location")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity8.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
                }
                if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().contentEquals("weather")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity5.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
                } else {
                    textToSpeech.speak( "Do not understand just tap on the screen Say again", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
                if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().contentEquals("calculator")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity3.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
                }
                else if(mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().contentEquals("exit")) {
                    finish();
                }
                else {
                    textToSpeech.speak("Do not understand just tap on the screen Say again", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }

                if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().contentEquals("yes")) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.surface);
                    surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
                    surfaceView.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
                        capture();
                    });
                    textRecognizer();
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(null);
                } else if (mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().contentEquals("no")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

            }
        }

    }
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @Nullable KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
            textToSpeech.speak("You are in main menu. just swipe right and say what you want", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textToSpeech.speak("you are in main menu. just swipe right and say what you want", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                }
            },1000);

        }
        return true;
    }
        public void buttonStart(View view) {

            startVoiceInput();
        }
    public void onPause() {
        if (textToSpeech != null) {
            textToSpeech.stop();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked up Android Lifecycle?

Comment: Yes. but already i have implemented text to speech method which reads the text on the screen that i have captured. but when this process will be done i want start another text To Speech method.

Comment: Just call the same code again?

Comment: You know how to excute Asynctask method

Comment: Enter "how to excute Asynctask " into a search engine - follow instructions.

Comment: You need to use co-routines jobs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70873621/how-to-start-another-text-to-speech-method-immediately-after-one-is-finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the same mode on text to speech ADD and it will play when the first one is done, ADD = ADD, FLUSH = reset

```
textToSpeech.speak("this will play when first is done", 
TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `startVoiceInput()` again.

You are setting this call for an onClick() handler on a TextView already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70873621/how-to-start-another-text-to-speech-method-immediately-after-one-is-finished

Comment: That is not the way to react on an answer.